# An outlier detection for this data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, anomaly-detection, outlier

I have a vector and want to detect outliers in it.

I need an outlier detection method (a non-parametric method) which can detect red points as outliers.
[image]

Edit:
I have a lot of vectors like this. The pattern is similar to this but the values are different. I mean we can see the height since the values are not constant but overall the patterns of outliers against the normal data are like this. This means in one place they beak the continuity of the blues points and go in different directions. Here is another figure.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take away all the data whose values are close to the 150 mark along the y axis? Can be done using `np.where(condition,val1,val2)` you can also plot a decision surface accordingly to seperate the data using meshgrids

Comment: Thanks. But it is not just this vector. I have different vectors but most of them from pattern aspect is like this (not from value aspect).

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://towardsdatascience.com/a-brief-overview-of-outlier-detection-techniques-1e0b2c19e561&ved=2ahUKEwjfgMeV5s_ZAhUGupQKHR26D14QjjgwC3oECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2KvUkN4tZoWSYqF6pJdgzb

Comment: Thanks. I have tested methods like IQR, median and STD but they don't provide desired results. DBScan and methods like that need parameter tunning which will not work for me.

Comment: Then use the default parameters and pretend they don't exist. I would try [DBScan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN), or, if your data without outliers are linear, outlier detection through [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

Comment: Is this a time series? Do you have to identify the outliers in real time, or is it OK to do so retroactively?

Comment: Yes. It is a time series data. What is your suggestion about retroactively?

Comment: I'm asking whether you need to detect the first anomalies right as they start happening (i.e. are you monitoring something), or is it OK to go in some time later and notice that an anomaly occurred (say) an hour ago?

Comment: Thanks. The method can be run routinely, for example, every 1 minute to examine that whether there is an outlier in the past one minute vector or not. You can imagine the points in the figures to belong to just one minute ago. So overall, I think yes. I mean it is not like supervised methods to detect each record when it enters the system. It is like unsupervised methods.

Comment: Updated my response based on your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is time series data, but it looks like it might be.

For any given narrow window of time there is a distribution that looks like it's centered somewhere a bit higher than y=200 and has a reasonably stable spread. So whatever that distribution is, that's your model.

Then monitor the recent window, and treat that as a sample. Perform a goodness of fit test against the model. If it fails then the points in the window are anomalous.

**UPDATE:** Based on what you say about the data representing roughly a minute of time, it looks like you could use a window that's about 1 second wide. Run a hypothesis test to see if the data in the window comes from the typical distribution, and if not, just mark all the points in that window as being anomalous. If you need finer resolution than 1s, simply shrink the window.

Comment: Thanks. So, how should if define the size of the window? because there is also the possibility of having a window that contains normal and outlier points. So if it fails it will detect all of the points as outliers which means increasing of false positives.

Comment: Are you concerned about the window's height capturing the typical points, or the width? Are you able to say anything about the dataset and application? That will make it easier to offer relevant ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Width. I have a lot of vectors like this. The pattern is similar to this but the values are different. I mean we can see the height since the values are not constant but overall the patterns of outliers against the normal data are like this. This means in one place they beak the continuity of the blues points and go in different direct

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the information you are providing in the comments here? Your remarks here are highly relevant to the approach. Also I would emphasize that if you are able to say anything about the dataset and application, that would be very helpful. (I understand that you may not be able to.)

Comment: I edited. This vector is the output of some processes which can contain some outliers which are caused by some illegal manipulation in data.